# how do you add inline styles in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi so this what I have in jquery however it doesn't seem to work, am I missing something?

```
 modalClose.on("click", () => {
        modalContainer.removeClass("modal-open");
        modalContainer.attr("style", "display:none");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the css function, passing it an object with the properties, you use camel case rather than hyphens.

```js
modalClose.on("click", () => {
        modalContainer.removeClass("modal-open");
        modalContainer.css({display: 'none'});
});
```

```js
//Use camel case for properties with hyphens. style="display: none; background-color: #FFFFFF"
jQuery('.youritem').css({display: 'none', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'})
```

To remove a property from your html send an empty string to the property, the following removes both the display and background-color properties.

```js
jQuery('.youritem').css({display: '', backgroundColor: ''})
```